Unable to access result of assignment to UseState
The parent component doesn't seem to access the ErrorMessage   I get this error...
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {error_msg}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
I checked and error_msg is the error message.
in the parent component I have...
function App() {

const [ErrorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

 const handleClickUpdate = async (event) => {
 
       ...
    const error_msg = Validation(postData)  
    setErrorMessage(error_msg)
   ...
 }
   <button type="submit" onClick={() => 
 handleClickUpdate({stuff})}>Update</button>


return (
     <div>
         <Submit setSomethingElse={somethingElse} setErrorMessage={(error) =>setErrorMessage(error)} ErrorMessage={ErrorMessage} />
     </div>
   <div className="error-message"> {ErrorMessage}</div>
 );

}

So in the child component:
  function Submit({ setSomethingElse, setErrorMessage, 
  ErrorMessage }) {



 const handleSubmit = async (event) => {

     ...
      setErrorMessage('Error Message')
     ...

}

But errorMessage is empty even after the assignment. Am I not passing in the prop correctly?
  return (
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        ...           
        <div>{ErrorMessage}</div>
     </form>
       );

}


if Submit is the child then by looking at App component you are not passing error message to it as a props

Can you provide some more code of both child and parent component?

What other code is needed?  Everything else is unrelated to the error message.  How would I pass in ErrorMessage?  It gets set inside the child right?

Please provide a more complete example, see [mre]. You are destructuring ErrorMessage from props but passing it as errorMessage. So naturally it'd be undefined until you correct the typo

you have a typo you use "errorMessage" but your prop is "ErrorMessage"

I added a lot to the code and corrected the error message.  Now the Submit Error causes an error.  I hope it's clear now?

Actually I may just close this question as it's changed.

The parent would need to pass not just the state setter, but also the state getter/value.
function App() {

const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');


  
return (
     <div>
         <Submit setErrorMessage={setErrorMessage} errorMessage={errorMessage}/>
     </div>
 );

}


and then have the child handle that prop like so..
function Submit({ setErrorMessage, errorMessage }) {



 const handleSubmit = async (event) => {

     ...
      setErrorMessage('Error Message')
     ...

}

  return (
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        ...           
        <div>{errorMessage}</div>
     </form>
       );

}


I tried this.  The ErrorMessage is defined but empty.  I updated the question accordingly.  Is something missing?

Instead of passing the function directly as a prop can you try this:


function App() {

const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');


  
return (
     <div>
         <Submit setSomethingElse={somethingElse} setErrorMessage={(error) =>setErrorMessage(error)} errorMessage={errorMessage} />
     </div>
 );

}



And in the child component you can just use the function like you are already doing.

This only adds an extra function in the middle, it does not change the functionality in any way

Now the Submit button causes an error.  I clarified in the question.  Is it clear?

This fixed the initial problem.  Thanks!

Actually it's now printing the error message twice.  Ugh

There's no chance this fixes any problems. Passing a function reference directly vs creating a lambda function that calls the original with the same parameter will literally only add an extra step to the function call.

Not sure if it was this or my correcting the typo which fixed the initial issue.
